# Pasar data desde firebase firestore a libreria de React JS "react-table"

Tags: firebase, datatables, reactjs

necesito pasar información desde firestore (la nueva BD de firebase) a la libreria react-table (libreria de datable), es sencillo pasar información mediante .map a algún

u otro elemento y que se repita según la cantidad de items que contenga el array de objetos, pero no se como pasarle la información de la base de datos a la propiedad data={} de [React Table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table).

Estoy utilizando create-react-app en conjunto con Mobx y React Router V4.

Cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Según la propia documentación de [react-table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table) le pasas los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
<ReactTable
    data={[aquí donde estén almacenados tus datos (state o props)]}
    columns={[aquí los valores de los encabezados de las columnas]}
  />
```

De todas formar tu pregunta es poco concreta, ¿puedes replantearla por favor?.

Un saludo.